# Need a web framework for generating editable, sortable, filterable HTML tables

Tags: django, frameworks, html-table, web2py

We need to design a Web application. We have data which we want to represent in the form of editable/sortable/filterable grids.

We will communicate with our framework written in Python, so Python frameworks are natural choice. The two main Python web frameworks are Django and Web2Py. They seem comparable.
Looking at Django, I see only Django tables2 library for these purposes. However, out of box it only renders sortable tables, but no default support for filtering and editing is provided.
So all the buttons for editing/cells for filtering should be provided by hand.

Is there any Web Framework (Python preferred) where I can get this functionality for free?

PS. As Anthony mentioned, Web2Py has an excellent interface for generating the readable/sortable/filterable grids. I tried it, and it is really good!

Answer (score 2):

Try [this jQuery datatable plugin](https://datatables.net/) which has sortable, filterable options default works very good for me

and [this datatable extinction](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/) for **edit table cells, adding new and delete records to the table** (I didn't use it)

Answer (score 0):

web2py includes built-in [grid functionality](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM-grid-and-SQLFORM-smartgrid) that may suit your needs. It creates a grid based on data from a database table (as well as based on queries that join multiple tables). The [smartgrid](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM-smartgrid) adds the capability to browse a set of relationally linked database tables.

You can sort as well as search/filter a grid. The search functionality is easily customizable, allowing you to swap out the UI widget and/or the backend search function with custom code.

Currently, there is no inline editing of records (though that is planned, and I'm sure any contributions would be welcome). However, you can edit a record by clicking an edit button next to the record, which takes you to a separate edit form (and then back to the grid after submitting the update). There is a [recipe for crude inline editing](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1928/basic-inline-editing-in-sqlformgrid-no-plugin-no-javascript), but it displays each value in a form widget.

If the built-in grid isn't suitable, you could easily integrate a Javascript grid, such as [DataTables](https://datatables.net/index) or [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) (there is [a web2py recipe for inline editing with jqGrid](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1714/jqgrid-viewing-and-updating-data)). It should be fairly straightforward to set up a [web2py web service](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#Restful-Web-Services) to communicate with these grids via Ajax.

Feel free to ask for help on the [web2py Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/web2py).